# Powershell -join on a single [DateTime] ignores current culture info

Tags: datetime, powershell

I've found a weird Powershell (v2) behaviour for which I'm trying to find a fix or workaround.
The current culture on my system is en-GB for which the date format is dd/mm/yyyy as evidenced if I run this:

```
[PS] H:\Powershell>(get-date).tostring()
21/08/2014 11:30:51
```

If I have an array of [DateTime] objects, and attempt to join them, again this culture info is preserved.

```
[PS] H:\Powershell>$a=@((get-date),(get-date))
[PS] H:\Powershell>$a

21 August 2014 11:33:53
21 August 2014 11:33:53

[PS] H:\Powershell>$a -join ";"
21/08/2014 11:33:53;21/08/2014 11:33:53
```

However, if the object is a singleton, the culture info is lost and the format reverts to mm/dd/yyyy:

```
[PS] H:\Powershell>$a[0] -join ";"
08/21/2014 11:33:53
```

This is proving an issue as I have a number of attributes, some single, some array within an object that I'm exporting to csv. As a catch-all I'm running a "-join" on all of them with the idea that singletons shouldn't be affected, but they clearly are.

Is there any way to force a culture using the -join operator or have I discovered a bug? I've not checked V4, but this happens in 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me right in the face, wrap the scalar value in an array and the -join works as expected.

```
[PS] H:\Powershell>@(get-date) -join ";"
21/08/2014 12:31:14
```